# Creating Daily worksheets, archiving previous weeks worksheets

Tags: vba, archive, worksheet

I am trying to figure out how to archive week old worksheets.

A little background on my project:

I create two new worksheets every day that house daily report summaries and calculations that I review on a daily basis.  As of now, there are way too many worksheets open in the one excel file so it takes forever to open and send to people.

Ultimately, I would like to figure out how to save any worksheets that were created the previous week to another file.  I would like to save these all in a seperate (single) workbook, or somehow create a folder to house each workbook for each day that week.

So for example, I create 10 worksheets for the current week (2 for each day of the week, Mon - Fri). Then, when I come in the following monday and start creating the worksheets for that week, the old sheets would be put into another workbook.

The code I currently use to create the worksheets every day:

```
TD = Format(Date, "yyyy.mm.dd")

On Error GoTo Make_Sheet
    Sheets("Open_" & TD).Activate

    Sheets("Open_" & TD).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=x1Up
Exit Sub

    Make_Sheet:
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Print")).Name = "Open_" & TD
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Open_" & TD

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Open_" & TD).Tab
   .Color = 5296274
   .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

The code will check to see if the current date's worksheet already exists (using the date as the title of the worksheet), if it does it clears it.  Otherwise it will create the new worksheet.  It will also colour code the tab (since I create 2 each day).  I have another identical set of code to create the second daily worksheet.

Thanks in advance,

-Tuques

Comment: It's all those `Activate`s and `Select`s that make it slow. Restructure the code to not use those things... example..  `Cells.Delete Shift:=x1Up` does the same thing as having it on 2 lines using select.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but change `Shift:=x1Up` to `Shift:=xlUp`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro to copy all sheets to a new workbook, save and close the new workbook. Delete all sheets but the first one and then clear the contents of the remaining sheet.
Not sure what sheets you want to preserve.

```
    Sub New_week()
 NWeek = MsgBox("Is this the start of a new week?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

    If NWeek = 6 Then

      Dim fname As String
       'Create new Workbook name.  
        'Add path if you want it in a specific folder
     fname = "Week" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".XLSX"
      'copy all sheets
     Sheets.Copy
         'save to new file
        With ActiveWorkbook
         .SaveAs FileName:=fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
         .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With

    'Delete all sheets except first
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Do While Worksheets.Count > 1
       Worksheets(2).Delete
      Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Clear contents of first sheet
    Sheets(1).UsedRange.Clear

    End If
```